# How to pop up an alert in Python and at the same time keep the process running?

Tags: python, popup, alert

I have a sample script below. The alert message will pop up but the user will have to acknowledge before the script could continue to run. So how do I pop up an alert in Python and at the same time keep the process running?

```
import random
import time
x = 0
while x <= 20:
    a = random.randint(1, 100)
    print (a)
    if a <= 10:
        ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, "The number generated is less than 10", "ALERT", 1)
    x += 1
    time.sleep(.5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [threading.Thread](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/threading.html#thread-objects).

This launches the alert in a separate thread, so that it does not block the main thread.

```
import random
import time
import threading

def alert():
    ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, "The number generated is less than 10", "ALERT", 1)

for _ in range(20):
    a = random.randint(1, 100)
    print (a)
    if a <= 10:
        thread = threading.Thread(target=alert)
        thread.start()
    time.sleep(.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or on *nix using *Notify* from the *gi.repository*

```
import random
import time
import threading
import gi
gi.require_version('Notify', '0.7')
from gi.repository import Notify

def alert():
    Notify.init("Random generator")
    Notify.Notification.new("The number generated is less than 10").show()

for _ in range(20):
    a = random.randint(1, 100)
    print (a)
    if a <= 10:
        thread = threading.Thread(target=alert)
        thread.start()
    time.sleep(.5)
Notify.uninit()
```